# align to right subfigure

Tags: horizontal-alignment, subfloats

I have a figure with 4 subfigures. I want the subfigures on the right to be aligned to right, I use  \usepackage[export]{adjustbox} but it doesn't seem to work.

```
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}

\begin{figure}[H]
\begin{subfigure}{0.45\textwidth}
\includegraphics[scale=0.8]{emb1try4}
\caption{} \label{fig:}
\end{subfigure}
\hspace*{0cm} % separation between the subfigures
\begin{subfigure}{0.45\textwidth}
\includegraphics[scale=0.55, right]{emb1try1}
\caption{} \label{fig:}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}{0.45\textwidth}
\includegraphics[scale=0.4]{emb1try2}
\caption{} \label{fig:}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}{0.45\textwidth}
\includegraphics[scale=0.6, right]{emb1try3}
\caption{} \label{fig:}
\end{subfigure}
```

[image]

Comment: Use \hfill or \hspace{\fill}.